# SSE Shift Instruction zeroes the vector with _mm_set1_epi32() for the count vector?

Tags: sse, simd

Here's the situation: `m3 = _mm_srli_epi32(m2, 23);` does exactly what is expected,

`m3 = _mm_srl_epi32(m2, shift);` however (`shift` being initialized as `__m128i shift = _mm_set1_epi32(23);`) yields zero.

I've checked and `shift` does have the value it should have. Is there something simple I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`_mm_srl_epi32 (__m128i a, __m128i count)`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psrlw:psrld:psrlq) takes the count as the low *64* bits of the count vector.  `set1_epi32(32)` is `(23<<32) | 23` which is a huge number which shifts out all the bits.

SSE shifts saturate the count (unlike scalar shifts which mask the count).

**You want `_mm_cvtsi32_si128(int)` to zero-extend a single `int` into a `__m128i`**, or if your shift count is already in a vector you need to isolate it in the low 64 bits of a vector with an AND, shuffle, or whatever.

`movq xmm,xmm` can zero-extend a 64-bit element to 128, but there's no equivalent for 32-bit elements.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a `movq xmm,xmm`? I only see instructions to/from general-purpose registers/memory (but also `movd` which zero-extends 32bit integers): https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movd:movq.

Comment: @chtz: Yes, it's the SSE2 version of the MMX `movq mm,mm/mem` opcode, not the REX.W version of `movd xmm, r32/m32`.  It has a different entry in the ISA ref manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movq.  It's the same opcode normally used for `movq xmm, [mem]` without a REX prefix.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Btw: If you don't mind about what happens in the upper 64 bits, you can zero-extend the lowest 32 bits from a `xmm` register by [`PMOVZXDQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovzx) (requires SSE 4.1, though)